# OrientDB edge creation latency

Tags: performance, graph, orientdb, latency

I am using Tinkerpop Blueprints to create a OrientDB graph for a dataset with millions of nodes and 100M edges on a laptop with 16gb memory, 64-bit Ubuntu, 64-bit jvm.

Here are the results from our benchmarking – the vertices get added fine but each edge addition takes almost a second.

[Edge Creation Latency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIdc3.png)

Can you suggest what we are not doing right wrt to the edge creation and how we can get it to improve to a more reasonable latency?

Here's the code associated with the above table:

```
package orientdbtest

import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OType
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.{Direction, Edge, Vertex}
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient._
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.intent.OIntentMassiveInsert

object Example {

  def addRandomVertex(graph: OrientGraphNoTx, uuid: String) : Vertex = graph.addVertex("class:Random", "uuid", uuid)

  def addRandomEdge(source: Vertex, target: Vertex, id: String) = graph.addEdge(null, source, target, id)
  def createRandomNetworkDatabase(graph: OrientGraphNoTx, numNodes: Int, numEdges: Int, useLightWeightEdges: Boolean):(Long, Long) = {  

    if (graph.getVertexType("Random") == null) {
        println("Creating random type")
        val random_vertex_type: OrientVertexType = graph.createVertexType("Random")
        random_vertex_type.createProperty("id", OType.STRING)
      } else {
        println("Random type exists")
      }

    val timeStartNodeCreation = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val nodeList: List[Vertex] = Range(0,numNodes).toList.map(x => addRandomVertex(graph, x.toString()))

    val timeEndNodeCreation = System.currentTimeMillis()

    println("Time to create " + numNodes + " is " + (timeEndNodeCreation-timeStartNodeCreation))

    val nodeListFirstHalf = nodeList.slice(0,nodeList.length/2)
    val nodeListSecondHalf = nodeList.slice(nodeList.length/2+1,nodeList.length)

    var edgeID = 1
    if(useLightWeightEdges) graph.setUseLightweightEdges(true)
    val timeStartEdgeCreation = System.currentTimeMillis()
    // createEdges from first half to the second half

    nodeListFirstHalf.foreach(sourceVertex => {
       nodeListSecondHalf.foreach(targetVertex => {
         while(edgeID < numEdges)
         {
             addRandomEdge(sourceVertex, targetVertex, edgeID.toString())
             edgeID = edgeID +1
             graph.commit()
         }
         })
    })

    val timeEndEdgeCreation = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("Time to create " + edgeID + " is " + (timeEndEdgeCreation-timeStartEdgeCreation))
    (0L, 0L)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val numNodes = 10
    val numEdges = 25
    val useLightWeightEdges = false

    val uri: String = "plocal:target/database/random_sample_" + numNodes + "_" + numEdges + useLightWeightEdges.toString()
    val graph: OrientGraphNoTx = new OrientGraphNoTx(uri)

    graph.setKeepInMemoryReferences(false);
    graph.getRawGraph().getLocalCache().setEnable(false)
    graph.declareIntent(new OIntentMassiveInsert())
    try {
      createRandomNetworkDatabase(graph, numNodes, numEdges, useLightWeightEdges)
      graph.declareIntent(null)
    } finally {
      graph.shutdown()
    }
    println("Adios")
  }
}
```